# I couldn't upload images using Django Rest-framework

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, django-rest-framework, image-uploading

I couldn't upload images using Django Rest-framework through [POSTMAN](https://www.getpostman.com/) , But I can do the same using **Django Admin**. When I try to debug the code, It's found that, `serializer.is_valid()` is always false.

These are my code parts,

**views.py**

```
class imageuploadView(APIView):
    def post(self, request,format=None):
        serializer=ImageSerializer(data=request.data)
        print serializer
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return  Response(data={"detail":"Image Uploaded !"})#data
        else:
            return Response(data={"detail":"Not Uploaded"})
```

**models.py**

```
class ImageUploadModel(models.Model):
    usr_id=models.IntegerField()
    upImg=models.ImageField(upload_to='media/')
    caption=models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None)
```

**serializer.py**

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    upImg = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None,use_url=True)
    class Meta:
        model=ImageUploadModel
        fields=('usr_id','upImg','caption')
```

**settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/static/',
)

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'media')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
```

Here is my [Source Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0DlE-Qi4Fu6UDNjb25SR1pYb0E/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

You can delete additional field in your serializer, `models.ImageField` will use `serializer.ImageField` by default.

```
class ImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model=ImageUploadModel
        fields=('usr_id','upImg','caption')
```

It should just work, your view code is correct
You could also use `generics.CreateAPIView` to reduce a code.

```
class imageuploadView(generics.CreateAPIView):

    queryset = ImageUploadModel.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer
```

If it will not work, please update your answer with a `serializer.errors`, you can check it in `else` case

Comment: Tried, but problem remaining there :(

Comment: I updated Question with my Source Code, That may useful for you

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge did you tried upload image via browable API which provided by DRF, try it and say how it works with images. And add `serializer.errors` message instead of your sources. Your code looks correct

Comment: I can see "POST" button provided by DRF but, there is no File browsing button. So I used POSTMAN and I got the response as " {"usr_id":["This field is required."],"upImg":["No file was submitted."]}  "

Comment: postman-screenshot - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0DlE-Qi4Fu6QWwxM1RkaEhnZlk/view

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge try add parsers into your view `parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser,)`

Comment: No more change :(