# Django Rest Framework: Uploading a Image

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, postman

I can't save the image to the image field.
**Error**

```
"image": [
    "No file was submitted."
]
```

**models.py**

```
class MyImages(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='myphoto', null=False,       max_length=255, blank=False)
```

**views.py**

```
class ImageList(APIView):
    parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FileUploadParser,)

    def post(self, request):
        file_serializer = MyImageSerializer(data=request.data)
        if file_serializer.is_valid():
            file_serializer.save()
            return Response(file_serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(file_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**serialiser.py**

```
class MyImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MyImages
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'image')
```

when using postman for file upload the file name is returned in view.py instead of the file object.

I have also seen these threads but not working
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20303252/django-rest-framework-imagefield) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41374640/i-couldnt-upload-images-using-django-rest-framework)

Comment: Are you using `form-data` option in POSTMAN ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge yes

Comment: what are the headers are you sending in the request ?

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta I am using postman and it automatically detects the header. I no need to write header.

Comment: @bSr can you add POSTMAN screenshot too ?

Comment: use  'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' header

Answer (score 1):

`FileUploadParser` populates `request.data` with a `file` key containing uploaded file.

However, `ImageSerializer` needs to serialize `image` this from the request.

Ergo, you need to specify fields explicitly. *e.g.*

```
class ImageFileField(serializers.Field):
    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return obj.image.url

    def to_internal_value(self, data):
        return data['file']


class MyImageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    name = serializers.CharField()
    image = ImageFileField(source='*')

    class Meta:
        model = MyImages
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any bug in your code when I tried to reproduce the error.
Make sure that **uncheck** the `application/json` content type
[image]

Then the postman console will be as follows,
[image]

Comment: Worked! it's my mistake I was using the name 'file' instead of 'image' as field name when passing the image to the postman.